# How to Add variables to package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json

I'm using ReactJS, and in the `package.json` file, I want to change my deploy URL dynamically based on a variable. I have two different servers: "stg" and "dev" with separate deploy URL.

Something like this:

```
const deployServer = "dev" or "stg"

   "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "deploy":"aws s3 sync build/ s3://"+deployServer+"-base-viewers-web-app"
},
```

How can I use that variable in the `package.json` file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. As far as I know, NPM does not have any kind of templating syntax. You can use two different scripts (deploy-stg and deploy-dev).

Comment: I guess I have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an environment variable when the server is started:

```
REACT_ENV=stg npm start
```

Then in your package.json file you may use:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node scripts/start.js",
  "build": "node scripts/build.js",
  "test": "node scripts/test.js",
  "deploy":"aws s3 sync build/ s3://REACT_ENV-base-viewers-web-app"
},
```

Comment: tnx, I will try that